# Doctrine ORM Update Row with ID

Tags: doctrine

Is there a way to update a row directly with and ID? I just want the ability to update a table row field without querying for the object first. I tried this...

```
    $id = 1;
    $s = new Sandbox();
    $s->setId($id);
    $s->setFname('moon');
    $e = $em->merge($s);
    $em->flush($e);
```

and it tried to do an update to the database, however, it failed because it tried to update all the undefined fields as well whereas I just want to update the fname field.

Thanks

Comment: What's the use case here? If the user selects this ID then it's a good idea to check if this ID exist in the database before doing an update (unless you can guarantee it's not being changed in between).

Comment: Yes assume the id exists, the above was an example. Today I query for the entity, set a bunch of things, then presist and flush it. I want to eliminate the query if I know the id.

Comment: Why do you merge then flush?

Comment: I don't have a reason, just trying to get it tow work.

Answer (score 2):

```
$id = 1;
$s = $em->getReference('Sandbox', $id);
$s->setFname('moon');
$em->persist($s);
$em->flush($s);
```